# ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output with label 'videooutput' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-stream-radio module, but a few times i get this error using it. How could i solve it? My code:

```js
const NodeMediaServer = require('node-media-server');

const config = {
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60
  },
  http: {
    port: 8080,
    allow_origin: '*',
    mediaroot: 'F:/VMediaServer/mediaroot'
  },
  trans: { ffmpeg: 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe', tasks: [ { app: 'live', ac: 'aac', vc: 'libx264', hls: true, hlsFlags: '[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3:hls_flags=delete_segments]', dash: true, dashFlags: '[f=dash:window_size=3:extra_window_size=5]' } ] }
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config)
nms.run();
```

Comment: Since you don't have a control over FFmpeg filters (I'm commenting only because I've seen that error message before running FFmpeg) it must be a bug in `node-media-server`. A couple notes: (1) this project has gone dormant (last release 2018) so you won't get much support if any (2) Is there a reason why the values of `hlsFlags` and `dashFlags` are enclosed in brackets? You can remove them and see if it does anything.

Comment: I messed it up, sorry, i posted the wrong code. I'm using it with `live-stream-radio` not with `node-media-server` ... The livestream module using that tag.